# How to access the static variable in ngFor in angular2

Tags: angular

I have loop which access the component static variable.. If I use "let person of persons()" it doesnt work. Here persons method return multiple person.. getting "TypeError: self.context.persons is not a function" error

```
static persons: Array<PersonDirective> = [];    
get persons(){
    return PersonInvolvedComponent.persons;
}
```

html is below

```
    <person-directive *ngFor="let person of persons(); #idx = index"     (remove) = "removePerson(idx)">
    </person-directive>
```

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work. `#idx = index` is invalid though. It should be `let idx = index`.

Comment: Maybe the problem are the braces after `persons` in `let person of persons()`?

Comment: Yea could be, `get persons()` cannot be invoked by using `persons()`

Comment: yeah.. working without ()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your template to

```
<person-directive *ngFor="let person of persons; let idx = index"     (remove) = "removePerson(idx)">
</person-directive>
```

Getters are accessed as properties, not methods.