# Property Undefined but it is Defined Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a file in my angular project called `globals.ts` in the app folder next to `app.module.ts` and other such files.

This file contains global definitions throughout my application. Here is one of them:

```
export const canadianCities = [
"Calgary",
"Edmonton",
"Halifax",
"Hamilton",
"Kitchener",
"London",
"Montreal",
"Oshawa",
"Ottawa",
"Quebec City",
"Toronto",
"Vancouver",
"Victoria",
"Windsor",
"Winnipeg"
]
```

Now I am trying to access that array in one of my components. So in the TS file of that component I imported globals.ts with the following code snippet `import { canadianCities} from 'src/app/globals'`

This was the auto-import so I know it's right. Just to double check I added a console log in my ngOnInit to print the list.

The HTML file in my component is another story. I have the following snippet of code here

```
<select formControlName="location" class="form-group mb-3" name="" id="">
    <option value="">{{'FORM_FIELD_SELECT_CITY' | translate}}</option>
    <option *ngFor="let city of canadianCities" [value]="city" [selected]="city === businessUpdateForm.controls['location'].value">{{city}}</option>
</select>
```

Ignore most of it except for the ngFor. The problem is that apparently canadianCities doesn't exist, as I'm getting the error

```
"TS2339: Property 'canadianCities' does not exist on type 'PromoComponent'."
```

I've tried starting and stopping my application, I've double checked everything, and I have no idea why canadianCities is undefined when I clearly defined it. Any help works thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use imported classes, functions and variables in an angular 2 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41358479/how-do-i-use-imported-classes-functions-and-variables-in-an-angular-2-template)

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare a variable in your component to hold the external variable as the template is only able to access the variables and methods in its component class.

```
import { canadianCities}  from 'src/app/globals';

export class YourComponent {
  canadianCities = canadianCities;
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cyfdhb?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Besides, you don't need the `selected` attribute: `[selected]="city === businessUpdateForm.controls['location'].value"`. The form control will auto bind by selecting the option based on its value.