# How to import class in another component in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular 2 and TypeScript and I'm trying to following code in which I want to use the variable of Test class in my another component viz header.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
export class Test{
static var1:number=10;
}
```

var1 is static because I want to use it without making test instance.

Code in the another component viz header

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Test} from '../app.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  Template;`<h1> Hello</h1>
            <h1>{{Test.var1}}</h1>`
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

This code showing only hello not "10" which is a static variable.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Test} from '../app.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  Template:`<h1> Hello</h1>
            <h1>{{test.var1}}</h1>`
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private test: Test) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

> Mistakes

- use `template` not `Template`
- use `:` not `;` after template
- make instance in the constructor

Comment: I make object obj as obj = new Test();
and <h1> obj.var1</h1> is used in template
But not showing me 10 as a output

Comment: have you tried using `constructor(private test: Test) { }` ?

Comment: No. I simply add these statement in

 export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {}

Comment: please try this by adding same as stated in answer

Comment: I use this
constructor(private test: Test) {
obj = new Test();
}
But it showing me an error Cannot find name 'obj'

Comment: no need to use `obj = new Test()` when you declare this into constructor

Comment: use constructor(private test: Test) {
}
 how to print 10

Answer (score 1):

So even though you do not want to instantiate instances of Test, you will still need to use instance properties of your component.

Within your component simply bind the class Test to a an instance property, and access that property in the template.

```
test = Test;
```

Access this in the template with:

```
{{ test.var1 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Test } from './app.component';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    template: `<h1> Hello</h1><h1>{{var1}}</h1>`
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    var1 = Test.var1; // place static var into local var
    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working but why we can't access it directly.

Comment: Please see the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39193573 It appears that the template is scoped to the component instance and therefore it has no access to global or static variables. In my opinion this is a good thing. Global state should usually be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You had set the variable as public. you have initialized `Test` as a private property. Hence it's scope is just inside the component and not on the template.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] 
})

export class AppComponent {
}

@Injectable()
export class Test{
  static var1:number = 10;
}


import {Test} from '../app.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  Template;`<h1> Hello</h1>
  <h1>{{Test.var1}}</h1>`
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(test:Test) { }
   ngOnInit() {
   }
}
```

Here using **@Injectable()** decorator before test class,
And use the ***Test*** in **providers[]** of **app.module.ts**,
I hope it works..