# Static member is not accessible error on navbar component

Tags: angular

I keep getting the following error: `Static member is not accessible` at this point:

[image: <code><nav *ngIf="!authService.isLoggedIn" ...></nav></code>]

**auth.service.ts**

```
export class AuthService {
  public static get isLoggedIn() {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    return (user !== null &&
      ((user.emailVerified === false && user.providerData[0].providerId === 'facebook.com') ||
        ((user.emailVerified !== false))));
  }
}
```

**navbar.component.html**

```
<nav *ngIf="!authService.isLoggedIn" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" data-navbar="smart"></nav>
```

**navbar.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html'
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {}
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: why do you even need to have static method in service available via dependency injection?

Comment: @Xesenix recently switched from Visual Studio Code to Webstorm, and I am trying to refactor it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind static variable of component in HTML in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193538/how-to-bind-static-variable-of-component-in-html-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't need to inject `AuthService`,in the component just create a property to get the value from `AuthService.isLoggedIn`

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(){}

  get isLoggedIn () {
   return AuthService.isLoggedIn 
  }
}
```

template

```
<nav *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" data-navbar="smart">
</nav>
```

Comment: What is the difference between your way and `*ngIf="!isLoggedIn()"` `isLoggedIn () {
   return AuthService.isLoggedIn 
  }`